# Querying "Send Count" and "Last Send" in "Push Demographic Table"

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, mobilepush, data-views

There are a few fields that appear in the "Push Demographic Table" (Only Available in Data Designer - Contact Builder) but not on _PushAddress Dataview Table like "Send Count", "Last Application Open", and "Last Send".

Are there anyway to query these fields? Thank you very much

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are not exposed via the _PushAddress  or _PushTag data views unfortunately